# Show inline content with Ellipsis overflow in Jetpack Compose Text doesn't work

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

Tried to implement `Text` with timestamp. Found that easiest way it's use `inlineContent`. But it doesn't work well with `overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis`

```
@Composable
fun TextWithTimestamp(
    text: String,
    timestamp: String,
    maxLines: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {

    val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.White)) {
            append(text)
        }
        pushStyle(SpanStyle(fontSize = 14.sp))
        appendInlineContent("timestamp", timestamp)
        pop()
    }

    val inlineContent = remember(text) {
        mutableMapOf(
            "timestamp" to InlineTextContent(
                placeholder = Placeholder(
                    height = 20.sp,
                    width = 20.sp,
                    placeholderVerticalAlign = PlaceholderVerticalAlign.Center,
                ),
                children = {
                    Text(
                        text = it,
                        color = Color.Yellow,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    )
                }
            )
        )
    }

    Text(
        text = annotatedString,
        inlineContent = inlineContent,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
    )
}

@Preview(widthDp = 200)
@Composable
private fun PreviewTextWithTimestamp() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .border(1.dp, Color.Green)
    ) {
        TextWithTimestamp(
            text = "MedalParrot, MedalPanda, MedalCarrot and 83+ liked your clip!",
            timestamp = "1h",
            maxLines = 2,
        )
        Divider(color = Color.Green)
        TextWithTimestamp(
            text = "MedalParrot, MedalPanda, MedalCarrot and 83+ liked your clip!",
            timestamp = "1h",
            maxLines = 3,
        )
    }
}
```

Without `overflow`, it works as expected, but with `TextOverflow.Ellipsis`, only `...` is shown, but inline content doesn't.

In design, I have limitation of content width and defined max lines. The text can be any length:

[image: Preview with maxLines = 2 and maxLines = 3]